# Episode by episode DVD Rip to AVI on Windows 7

Tags: video, dvd, encoding, ripping, avi

I'm looking for a Windows tool to rip DVD files to AVI files.  [VidCode](http://vidcoder.codeplex.com/) looks cool, but it wants to  convert the whole DVD (all files in the VIDEO_TS folder) to one AVI.  I would like to pull each episode on the DVD to its own AVI.  Is their a way to that with VidCode, or another ripper?

My Plan B for VidCode is to manually separate files for each episode into their own VIDEO_TS folders.  Is this possible?  Is there an easy, lazy way to automate this?

This is on Windows 7

Comment: i use dvd decrypter command lines like this in a batch file:

%DVDDEXE% /MODE IFO /SRC J: /DEST "%EPSPATH%\EP01\" /VTS 1 /PGC 01 /SPLIT NONE /START /CLOSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [Cheekie_Moonkie guide](http://download.videohelp.com/cheekie_moonkie/guides/ddtool.html) to work nicely, and it looks like the tools (the process actually uses quite a lot of tools) used in it can be used elsewhere for other fascinating things.

*One note not covered in the guide:*
When you have decoded the DVD to .vob files and are about to use Auto Gordian Knot to produce .avi files, your are forced to choose from three options for "output size".  First I thought choosing a very large size would be safest.  It probably is, but it takes a very long time for just one 40 minute .avi.  Choosing 80% target quality provides more than enough viewing quality on my laptop, but using the quality option seems the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could rip the entire disk using your favorite ripping tool. Then process the output with Handbrake. I use Handbrake to turn TV Series DVDs into individual media files. IIRC, install VLC before Handbrake and it will do some ripping as well.

Comment: VidCoder has the same functionality has HandBrake, so switching to that wouldn't help. The problem is most likely that the DVD has put all of the videos in one title and separated the episodes out by chapters.

Answer (score 0):

[OGMRip](http://ogmrip.sourceforge.net/) can rip each episode separately, assuming they are in separate video tracks.

Comment: I've edited my post to include this, but I'm looking for Windows tools.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work for [DeskShare](http://www.deskshare.com) (no current connection) and their Rip DVD Plus can do what you're discussing.  Disclaimer: I didn't write the program but I did write the help and some of the web copy for it.

Answer (score 0):

DVDs do sometimes put multiple episodes into one title, but it's usually split up by chapter. You can just select which chapters you want and encode just that. VidCoder has that option. Failing that, you could just figure out where you need to split it and specify the start and end point in seconds.